# Script to restore MySQL from backup

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This may be an odd question but is it possible to have a .bat or some sort of script that can restore MySQL from a backup using a script in Windows? What I'm trying to accomplish is an easier way to restore old snapshots of data. My user base is not technical so giving them the ability to drop a backup into a folder and click a script shortcut would be ideal.

Comment: Workbench allows to write Python scripts but it's a visual tool at its core. I think that for automation you're better off with MySQL command-line utilities. Said that, I'm afraid your questions is too vague to be answered here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The MySQL DB is running on Linux. So to better explain, I have automatic backups set up and they are being sent to a Samba folder. It would be ideal if a user were to place a backup into let's say "Please Restore" that it would automatically get loaded into a test DB so they can then use MS Access to view the data.